# Move 'composer.phar' ssh

Tags: composer-php, mv

I install composer via an ssh command on my 1and1 server.
I would like to move the file to / usr / local / bin / composer with the command "mv composer.phar / usr / local / bin / composer"

I get an error and I have not found answers after some research.

```
Error: mv: cannot stat 'composer.phar': No such file or directory
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see the .phar file when you get a directory listing, `ls -la` ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the command below to load composer.phar

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject/ --filename=composer

**Note: /opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject/
this is the directory path where you want to download**